# How to hide the selected arraylist?

Tags: php, arraylist, hidden-field

The code that i use for arraylist and the way i code for hide the arraylist is like this

```
<?php 
    echo arraySelect($companies, 
                     'project_company', 
                     'type="hidden" 
                      class="text" 
                      size="1"', 
                      ($project->project_company=2), true);
?>
```

But when i test this code it doesn't show me the arraylist hidden, so can i know where the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: we don't know what `arraySelect` does. Please show us some code

Comment: arraySelect is just a dropdown list, what i want is just hide the dropdownlist, is the arraySelect code important affected can't hide the dropdown list?

Comment: basing on information you provided - if you want to hide the arraySelect - just remove it from code. _If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer._

Comment: maybe the way i asked is wrong, i just can't figure out although i code `type = "hidden"`, the dropdown list is still appear, sorry for the question

Comment: no need to apoligzes. Now you put some more details here so I can help you :) please check my answer below. And it's not and PHP issue it's HTML issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If output of your function is something like:

```
<select type="hidden" name="foo">
   <option>bar</option>
   <option>bar</option>
   <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

it won't work as there is no `type` attribute for `<select>` HTML tags. `type=hidden` works for input's only.

You have to hide the dropbox using css:

```
<select name="foo" style="display: none;">
...
```